# Submit form when a checkbox is checked and getting data with POST

Tags: javascript, php, html

this is my form :

```
 <form class="form-horizontal" method="post" action=""  id="user_profile_private" name="user_profile_private">         
 <div class="onoffswitch">      
     <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch"  class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" checked>
     <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
     <div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
     <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
    </label>
 </div>
```

I've tried  `onChange="this.form.submit()"`
 and  `Onchange="document.getElementById('formName').submit()"`. In some point, I even succeed to submit my form but I could not be successful on getting the data. What I want is to submit the form and get the data  (if the checkbox (swich) on or off) in the same page with $_POST.

PS: I made this switch with http://proto.io/freebies/onoff/ maybe it helps.

The important thing is getting data with post because when I try to do that I always get an empty array with `var_dump($_POST);`

Comment: Maybee it's stupid, if you want to submit a form if two or three checkboxes are checked, your question is reasonable.  But if you really want to always submit your form if a checkbox is checked, you made something, wrong. Simply use a input[type="submit"] button[type="submit"] and change your question to, how do i style type="submit" like a type="checkbox"....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use jquery `$('selector').on('click');` or `$.click()` on this one. Consider this example:

```
<?php
// PHP form handling:

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    $checkbox_value = $_POST['onoffswitch'];
    echo '<script>alert("'.$checkbox_value.'");</script>';
}
?>

<!-- change the action="" to the name of this php file -->
<form class="form-horizontal" method="POST" action="index.php"  id="user_profile_private" name="user_profile_private">           
    <div class="onoffswitch">      
        <input type="checkbox" name="onoffswitch" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" id="myonoffswitch" value="1">
        <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="myonoffswitch">
            <div class="onoffswitch-inner"></div>
            <div class="onoffswitch-switch"></div>
        </label>
    </div>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#myonoffswitch').on('click', function(){
        if($(this).is(':checked')) {
            // if your checkbox is checked, submit the form
            $('#user_profile_private').submit();
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: i don't have knowledge of javascript. could you help me with this script? when i copy this code it doesnt work.

Comment: @suyilmaz in the following answer, i used jquery, did you already included it?

Comment: yes it works perfect when i click, the form submit but i could not get the data. var_dump says null

Comment: @suyilmaz check the edit, i added `action="index.php"` on the form, and added php processing

Answer (score 1):

Do something like that

```
$('.myonoffswitch').on('click',function(){

  if($(".myonoffswitch").is(':checked'))
     DO SOMETHING....
  else
      DO SOMETHING....
});
```